# Apply BeautifulSoup to XML data from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have Pandas DF which has XML data that needs to be parsed. When I apply BeautifulSoup to the pandas column that has XML, the results are not as expected. I see *None* when searching for an existing tag

Here is the dataframe, column CDATA has XML

[image]

here is a snippet of the code that prints None for the existing tag *logicalModel*

```
sampledata= df.loc[(df['PACKAGE_ID']==packageName)&(df['OBJECT_NAME']==viewName) ,['CDATA']].apply(str)
payload = sampledata.values[0]
bs4_xml = BeautifulSoup(payload, features="xml")
print(bs4_xml.logicalModel)
```

.apply(str) is including string in payload.

then I tried below to get rid of the index

```
sampledata= df.loc[(df['PACKAGE_ID']==packageName)&(df['OBJECT_NAME']==viewName) ,['CDATA']].values
BeautifulSoup(sampledata, features="xml")
```

but it gives the error:
*{TypeError}cannot use astring pattern on a bytes-like object*

When I read same XML from a flat file and apply BeautifulSoup, I can see Tag that I am looking for

```
with open("SampleXML") as fp:
     y = BeautifulSoup(fp, features="xml")
print(y.logicalModel)
```

Comment: does the `payload` string look exactly as you would expect? It looks like `apply(str)` includes the index in the string

Comment: yes, it includes the index. I just updated my original post. thanks

Comment: I think you need `.values[0, 0]` to get the string just `.values` is a numpy array.